# Select insert into composite primary key tables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-insert, select-into

I have a table with a composite primary key of 3 values:

```
SELECT sifra_kapit_proj,
       sifra_aktivnosti,
       sifra_funkcije,
       naziv_aktivnosti,
       row_version,
       sifra_programa
  FROM EFIN00123..aktivnost
```

The 3 starting with `sifra_` are the primary key. I need to equalize the content from this table and the same table in another database (any rows from table 2 that aren't in table 1 need to be inserted). Normally, I'm doing an insert into select along the primary key, but it won't work here.
How to go around doing that?

For clarification, how I normally go around equalizing tables. This does not work since both tables have the exact same sifra_aktivnosti (or any of the other two values), but have different total number of rows

````
insert into EFIN00123..aktivnost
select sifra_kapit_proj,sifra_aktivnosti, sifra_funkcije, naziv_aktivnosti,
row_version, sifra_programa
from EKUF00123..aktivnost where sifra_aktivnosti not in
( select sifra_aktivnosti from EFIN00123..aktivnost )```
````

Comment: *"but it won't work here."* Why won't an `INSERT` work?

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help

Comment: updated my first post with an example code of how I normally go about doing things. This table is an outlier, as 99% of our tables have just normal primary keys, not composites. What I have to do it take the table with more data and insert the missing rows into the other table. I could perhaps create a view that is a copy of the table with a additional colum that is a concatenate of the 3 values, effectively creating a new primary key to search/compare trough and do inserts, which can then be deleted?

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results otherwise it's hard to understand